# How to use 'on' on 'append' in jquery?

Tags: jquery

The HTML look like this：

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class='link'> <a href='http://www.1.com'></a></li>           
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li class='link'> <a href='http://www.2.com'></a></li>              
    </ul>
</body>
```

The js：

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".link a").each(function() {
        var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = a_href;

        if (parser.hostname == "www.1.com") {
            $(this).append('<img src="1.jpg"/>');
        } else if (parser.hostname == "www.2.com") {
            $(this).append('<img src="2.jpg" />');
        } 
    });

    $('body').append("<ul><li class='link'><a href='http://www.2.com'></a></li></ul>");
});
```

I want the appended  tag to also reflect the  insertion.

Here I just simplify my case, actually, the appended  is added by click, so I want to ensure that the  can be inserted even the  is added later.

Comment: What do you want to do with `.on()`?

Comment: Also, I don't see any point in `a_href` and `parser` variables. Why not to use `this`? [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/w0z9dm8b/).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I see you want to insert <img> tags inside your <a> but then you append another <ul> to the body at the end of the ready function? Are you wanting the appended <ul> tag to also reflect the <img> insertion? If so why not move the append before the .each() loop?

Comment: @Ryan You really catch what I mean. I want the appended <ul> tag to also reflect the <img> insertion. Here I just simplify my case, actually, the appended <ul> is added by click, so I want to ensure that the <img> can be inserted even the <ul> is added later.

Comment: @liyuhao so, once again: call `$(".link a").each(function() {` after `<ul>` is appended. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/w0z9dm8b/1/).

Comment: @Regent But in the actually case, the <ul> is added by click, I can not ensure the calling time.

Comment: @liyuhao it doesn't change statement: you should call `$(".link a").each(function() {` after `<ul>` is appended. Most probably in click event handler, as Ryan and Pete have already suggested in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to have an .on() attached to the body to listen for newly appended  tags so that you may do  insertions on any  tags in that .

Based on your reply to my comment I think you're going to have to do that in your click handler of what ever is being clicked...

```
$('selector').click(function(e){
  // add your new ul here
  // call imagify to add <img> to <a>
  imagify(e);
});

function imagify(e) {
  $(".link a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('img').length == 0) {
            var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = a_href;

            if (parser.hostname == "www.1.com") {
                $(this).append('<img src="1.jpg"/>');
            } else if (parser.hostname == "www.2.com") {
                $(this).append('<img src="2.jpg" />');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch it around and use `.appendTo()`, so that `.on()` can be chained correctly:

```
$("<ul><li class='link'><a href='http://www.2.com'></a></li></ul>").appendTo('body').on(/*...*/);
```

Comment: My problem is: I want the appended <ul> tag to also reflect the <img> insertion.
Here I just simplify my case, actually, the appended <ul> is added by click, so I want to ensure that <img> can be inserted even the <ul> is added later.